# How to stop execution test if 2 or more tests failed?

Tags: python, robotframework

Hello i have so issue when i try to stop test if 2 or more test failed, I'm using listener lib for this, I'm checking status, and when status "FAIL"  add to the counter, when counter == 2, tests must stop, but it doesn't.

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class PythonListener(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

def __init__(self):
    self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

def end_test(self, name, attrs):
    global result
    global count
    count = 0
    result = None
    print 'Suite %s (%s) start %s.' % (name, attrs['longname'], attrs['status'])
    if attrs['status'] == "FAIL":
        count += 1
        if count >= 2:
            result = BuiltIn.fatal_error(self)
            return result
```

Comment: Why do you want to stop the tests part-way through? What if more than two things are broken?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a report on the function of sending an email , after stopping the test, I 'll check the problem and re-run tests.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Do the tests take a long time to run? Are they interrelated? Why can't you check all of the problems at the end?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have about 600 tests, and by the time this is where - is 2-3 hours, tests are interconnected , this does not make sense to look that fell 150 tests , only two to identify the problem(sorry for my english)

Comment: have you verified your listener is being called? Have you verified that the `fatal_error` keyword is being called? Why are you passing `self` to `fatal_keyword` when it expects a string of text?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes i'm verified listener, fatal_error called, i remove self in fatal_keyword(my fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. However, even when you fix the syntax issues this solution won't work. A listener can't cause a test to fail. A listener is purely an observer, it can't run keywords. You can call `sys.exit()` but that will immediately terminate the test without generating a report.

What you will need to do is implement a keyword that every test case calls, which can examine the count variable defined by the listener. You could then call this keyword in every test setup or teardown.

An example of implementing a keyword and a listener in the same module can be seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28508009/7432

As to the problems in your code:

First, the indentation of the methods `__init__` and `__end_test__` is incorrect, causing those functions to be global functions rather than methods of the class.

Second, your `end_test` method resets the count to zero every time it is called. You need to make `count` an object attribute.

Third, you are calling `fatal_error` incorrectly. Change this:

```
result = BuiltIn.fatal_error(self)
```

... to this (note the parenthesis on `BuiltIn()`):

```
result = BuiltIn().fatal_error("failed due to failure >= 2")
```

But like I said earlier, you can call this keyword within the listener but it won't affect your test run.